# Inserting HTML content with CSS into Word/OneNote/etc

Tags: ms-office, office-js

It would be great if an Office Add-In could simply wrap a code highlighting library (like [highlight.js](https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js)), and drop the generated html + css into word/onenote/etc.

Does office-js support this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Office JavaScript APIs do support inserting HTML into Word and OneNote.  This HTML includes both plain HTML, and HTML with in-lined styling.

This means that what you need is to supply HTML with styles already in-lined into it.  Something like this should help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/computed-style-to-inline-style

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I got it working, here's what it looks like so far: ![image](https://augustnagro.com/images/syntaxhighlighter.png).

Comment: There are still a few things preventing the add-in from being better than simply copy-pasting into an ide, though. It would be great if we could insert html at the cursor position (Word.InsertLocation only has .start and .end), and I'm not sure how to add background shading through the api, which I can do manually with Format -> Borders & Shading.

Comment: For location, couldn't you get the current selection and then do an insert location of start (or replace, depending on what you want)?

Comment: For background shading,  I suggest you open a separate StackOverflow thread, so that someone who has more knowledge about this could help.